# is cos(iz) injective?

Tags: complex-analysis

I had an exam, and there was a question - `is cosh(z) injective?`
I presented it as cos(iz) (or cos(-iz), doesn't matter because it's an even function), but it didn't help because I don't know if *this* function is injective either.

Comment: Let $z_1=0$ and $z_2=2\pi i$, it is easy to see that 

$$z_1\neq z_2\qquad\text{and}\qquad\cos(iz_1)=\cos(iz_2)$$

Comment: your answer shows the function is not surjective..
shouldn't you show that for  $z_1$, you can get $cos(i z_1)$ that is different from another $cos(iz_1)$?

Comment: Recall that a function $f:X \to Y$ is injective if for all $x,y \in X$ we have $x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Comment: from what I know, a function is injective if for x, y we have $x \neq y$, $f(x)=f(y)$

Comment: @TzahiLeh No, a function $f:X\to Y$ is said injective if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: oh I get it.. sorry, I confused myself.
thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Just a sidenote, without specifying the domain this question might not be answered as injectivity is a concept which is always tied to the domain of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\cos(iz)=\cos(-iz)$ then by definition its not injective from $C$ to $C$.

Comment: why is that? I think it shows that the function isn't Surjective..

Comment: because for two values $x\neq y$ it does not follow that $f(x)\neq \f(y)$. Take $x=1$ and $x=-1$. In general every even function ist not injective if you dont restrict your domain.

Answer (score 1):

We have the function $\cosh:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

We can show that it isn't injective if we can find $x \neq y$ such that $\cosh{x} = \cosh{y}$.

(Relatedly, we can show that it isn't surjective if we can find $y$ such that there is no $x$ for which $\cosh{x} = y$.)

Because the function is even, it is easy to show that the function isn't surjective: take any $x\neq 0$ and define $y \equiv -x$. Then $x \neq y$, but $\cosh{x} = \cosh{y}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure whether a function is injective, simply try plugging in different values of x that give the same value of the function. In the case of cosine, try to remember if there exists two different value of x that would give the same cosine. In this case, they exist, in fact, many exist. $\cos{0}=\cos{2 \pi}$.